# Custom Dialog in lollipop is not working

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Custom dialog in my application is not working in lollipop. It is working in all other versions of android properly. I have used custom layout and custom style for my dialog. Here i added image of dialog.[image: Dialog]

The custom style which i used is

```
 <style name="ThemeDialogCustom">
 <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
 <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
 </style>
```